# Unhandled exception OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am working on object tracking using SURF for an assignment. My code runs on Ubuntu but my webcam doesn't work well on that so I need to make it work on Windows (Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.4.3) for my demo.

My code is based on this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

I'm guessing if this is solved, my code will also start working.

The error I get is:

**Unhandled exception at 0x75b92eec in Sift.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x00c6e328..**

Any idea how to solve this? I think I have added all the necessary libraries because it builds successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to debug the code, an execution time error is hard to trace. Probable you have some image without features.

Comment: The error is at this line: detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );

The picture opens. I checked it by displaying it in a window. Also it has features. I've tested it in Ubuntu.